# JSON.parse( xhr.responseText ) unexpected string error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string " when I try to parse my xhr.responseText, I've looked for answers but cannot find any that can relate to my problem directly. I seem to understand that my xhr.responseText may be JSONP because it is manipulated byt the callback but that doesn't help me, how can I just have a JSON? I want to be able to use my JSON in my Javascript with the Google Maps API. I'm really confused and just trying to make this work, thanks for reading and possibly helping.

Here's my PHP script.

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

require("include/param_bd.inc");
try {
    $connBD = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHote; dbname=$dbNom", $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $connBD->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit("Erreur lors de la connexion Ã  la BD :<br />\n" . $e->getMessage());
}
try {
    $reqZaps = "SELECT * FROM leszaps";
    $prepReqZaps = $connBD->prepare($reqZaps);
    $prepReqZaps->execute();
    $prepReqZaps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit("Erreur lors de l'exÃ©cution de la requÃªte SQL :<br />\n" . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\nREQUÃŠTE = " . $reqZaps);
}
if (!( $infoZaps = $prepReqZaps->fetch() ))
    $msgErreur = "Aucun Zap trouvé";
else {
    do
    {
        $id = $infoZaps->id;
        $coordinates = $infoZaps->coordinates;
        $arrondissement = $infoZaps->arrondissement;
        $numerocivil = $infoZaps->numerocivil;
        $rue = $infoZaps->rue;
        $nombatiment = $infoZaps->nombatiment;
        echo "{\n";
        echo "\t\"id\": \"$id\",\n";
        echo "\t\"coordinates\": \"$coordinates\",\n";
        echo "\t\"arrondissement\": \"$arrondissement\",\n";
        echo "\t\"numerocivil\": \"$numerocivil\",\n";
        echo "\t\"rue\": \"$rue\"\n";
        echo "\t\"nombatiment\": \"$nombatiment\"\n";
        echo "}\n";
    }
    while ($infoZaps = $prepReqZaps->fetch());

}
$prepReqZaps->closeCursor();
$connBD = null;

if ($msgErreur != "undefined" && $msgErreur != null) {
    echo "{\n";
    echo "\t\"erreur\":\n";
    echo "\t{\n";
    echo "\t\t\"message\": \"" . str_replace("\"", "\\\"", $msgErreur) . "\"\n";
    echo "\t}\n";
    echo "}\n";
}
?>
```

And here's my Javascript script

```
var xhr;
var donneesChargees = false;
var objReperes;
var reperes;

chargerKml();

function chargerKml() {

    var lienDocChargement = './script_load_kml_get.php';

    var erreur = false;

    chargerScriptAsync('./script_load_kml_bd.php', function(){
        console.log("Les ZAP ont été chargées dans la base de données");
    });
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpRequest = new
                ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    try {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Erreur: Impossible de créer l\'objet XMLHttpRequest');
        erreur = true;
    }
    if (!erreur)
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = xhrCallback;
        xhr.open('GET', lienDocChargement, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
}

function xhrCallback()
{

    if (xhr.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (xhr.status != 200)
            alert('Erreur: La requête HTTP a échoué (code=' + xhr.status + ')');
        else
        {
                            objReperes = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );
            creerReperes();
        }
    }
}

function creerReperes()
{

    try { 

        var strReperes;

                //$arrondissement = objReperes.$arrondissement;
        strReperes = '[' + xhr.responseText + ']';
        strReperes = strReperes.replace(/[\n\r\t]/g, '');
        strReperes = strReperes.replace(/}{/g, '}~{');
        strReperes = strReperes.split('~');     
        var coordonnees;
                var id;
        reperes = '[';
        for (var i = 0; i < strReperes.length; i++){
                         var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
                        id = strReperes[i].split(',')[0];
                        id = id.match( numberPattern );
            coordonnees = strReperes[i].split(',')[1] + ',' + strReperes[i].split(',')[2];
            coordonnees = coordonnees.replace(/"/g, '');
            coordonnees = coordonnees.replace('coordinates: ', '');
            coordonnees = coordonnees.split(',');
            reperes += '{"long": ' + coordonnees[0] + ', "lat": ' + coordonnees[1] + ', "id": ' + id + '}';
            if (i != strReperes.length - 1) {
                reperes += ', ';
            }
        }
        reperes += ']';
        reperes = JSON.parse(reperes);


    } catch (e) {
        alert('ERREUR: La réponse AJAX n\'est pas une expression JSON valide.');
        return;
    }


}
```

As you can see in creeReperes() i need to do some unorthodox manipulation with the xrhresponsetext instead of using a JSON.

[image: Here's an image of my error]
Oh and sorry if some of the code is in french.

Comment: Do not do what you are trying to do with `echo`, use http://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: What @Cheery said. And not only for the results, but also in case someting goes wrong; the error messages in the `catch` blocks. If you state that you'll output json in the header, you should not start outputting html.

Comment: By the way, you can easily see in the developers tools what the exact output of you ajax request is.

Comment: Not only are you manually building a serialized data structure which is highly error prone, but what you are outputting is actually several separate structures (1 per loop iteration) instead of one. Follow @Cheery's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you everyone I had actually tried doing an array and echoing the json.encode (the method you see in the code was my teacher's) but what I had tried didn't work. I tried again and it worked... so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!( $infoZaps = $prepReqZaps->fetch() ))
    $msgErreur = "Aucun Zap trouvé";
else {

    $rows = array();
    while ($infoZaps = $prepReqZaps->fetch()) {
        $rows[] = $infoZaps;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}

$prepReqZaps->closeCursor();
$connBD = null;
```